# Porque obtengo un valor no numérico?

Tags: php

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /box/script.php on line 29
```

Este es mi código:

```
$cont = 1;
$longest = $cont;
$number = $myArray[0];

for($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++) {

    if($myArray[$i] == $myArray[$i+1]){
    
        $cont++;
        
        $longest = $cont;
        
        $number = $myArray[$i];
    
    } else {
        
        $cont = 1;
    }
    
    if($cont > $longest){
    
        $longest = $cont;
        $number = $myArray[$i];
    }

}

echo("Longest: " + $longest + "\n" + "Number: " + $number);
```

La linea 29 sería la siguiente

```
echo("Longest: " + $longest + "\n" + "Number: " + $number);
```

Estoy tratando de encontrar el numero que se repite mas veces dentro de un array de manera consecutiva.

Este sería mi array:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8);
```

Comment: Has realizado 3 veces la misma pregunta casi en el mismo momento, de distinta forma pero con el mismo objetivo.  ¿Porque no esperas a que te contesten en una antes de volverlo a preguntar?  o bien ¿porque no borras las que ya no necesitas respuesta si es que has avanzado en su resolución? ¿O porque no editas la pregunta si ha sufrido variaciones?  Vas a llenar SOes de preguntas casi iguales y nos vas a volver locos intentando ayudarte cuando quizás ya has avanzado y ya no te hacen falta algunas preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando de realizar una operaciòn invalida sumando un valor no numerico (string + int) lo cual es incorrecto, para evitar esto puedes concatenar los valores de esta forma utilizando el [operador de concatenaciòn](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php):

```
echo("Longest: ".$longest."\n"."Number: ".$number);
```

---

Ademàs tu còdigo tiene un problema, este puede tratar de buscar un elemento que no existe en el array, valida que `$i+1` sea siempre menor a la logitud del array:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8);
$cont = 1;
$longest = $cont;
$number = $myArray[0];

for($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++) {
    
    if(($i+1)<count($myArray)){  //*Validacion
        
      if($myArray[$i] == $myArray[$i+1]){
    
          $cont++;
        
          $longest = $cont;
        
          $number = $myArray[$i];
    
     } else {
        
          $cont = 1;
      }
    }
    if($cont > $longest){
    
        $longest = $cont;
        $number = $myArray[$i];
    }

}

echo("Longest: ".$longest."\n"."Number: ".$number);
```